# OpenLayers3 Using an Angular class property in Style Function

Tags: angular, openlayers-3

I have an Angular2/4 app that I've created that uses OpenLayers3 to render a map for an island for the sandbox game Wurm Online. It works quite beautifully, replacing an older more kludgey version I created from pure JS.

Current Demo: http://www.wurmonlinemaps.com/maps/xanadubeta

Code Repo: https://github.com/WefNET/wurmonlinemaps-ng

I want to offer to the end users the ability to customize the colors of certain features rendered on the screen. Eventually, I'd like to use the localStorage concept to save user preferences.

What I hoped would work is not working: set a style property in a vector layer's stylefuncton to an Angular class property value.

**Basic Concept**

In this pseudo-code example, the "deedColor" Angular class property is set to a value, then I try to consume it within the style function:

```
export class AppComponent {
    deedColor: string = "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)";

    var deedStyleFunction = function (feature, resolution) {
        return [
        new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
              points: 4,
              radius: 11 / resolution,
              angle: Math.PI / 4,
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                  color: this.deedColor
           }),
        })
      ]
    }

    // hundreds of other lines
}
```

Sadly, the style function cannot figure out the Angular class property:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'deedColor' of undefined
```

After some experimentation, it seems I can't access any Angular object from within an OL StyleFunction.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a scope issue - try binding your function to the ng object:

```
deedStyleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {

}.bind(this);
```